# how to draw graph in php

Tags: php, mysql, graph, charts

Hi i am new in graph chart . please help me

I can fetch the record easily : by the MySQL query like :

```
SELECT `date` , hours, sum( `is_click` ) AS clicks, sum( `is_used` ) AS conversions, IFNULL( sum( `is_used` ) *100 / sum( `is_click` ) , 0 ) AS `CR` , sum( `cash_back_amount` ) AS 'Cost to User', sum( `cash_back_amount` ) / sum( `is_click` ) AS 'CPC', sum( `revenue` ) AS `revenue` , sum( `revenue` ) / sum( `is_click` ) AS `RPC` , sum( `revenue` ) - sum( `cash_back_amount` ) AS `profit` , count( hours ) AS 'count'
FROM (

SELECT `click_record`. * , DATE( click_record.`date_time` ) AS `date` , HOUR( click_record.`date_time` ) AS hours, ifnull( offer_content.cashback_amount, 0 ) AS cash_back_amount, ifnull( offer_content.revenue, 0 ) AS `revenue`
FROM `click_record`
LEFT JOIN offer_content ON offer_content.content_id = `click_record`.content_id
AND `click_record`.`is_used` =1
WHERE `click_record`.`is_click` =1
)aa
GROUP BY `date` , hours
```

this return the result like

[image]

and i need to generate graph like

[image]

i used many staff but i am unable to do please help me.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1');   // Don't need to specify chart libraries!
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'ColumnChart',
          dataTable: [['', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'France', 'RU'],
                      ['', 700, 300, 400, 500, 600, 800]],
          options: {'title': 'Countries'},
          containerId: 'vis_div'
        });
        wrapper.draw();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="vis_div" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable" ?

Comment: Yes, but why are you unable? Something went wrong?

Comment: code you have shared is working. But it looks like bar chart and i think you want a line chart https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: i could not understood what to do b'coz its first time

Comment: you must have an idea about how your data visualization look like. Your query result have different columns you have to decide which all fields become the axis of graph. Then only some one can help you.

Comment: i need x as date y as hour and rows like profit revenue and cost

Comment: Use a javascript library to work with graphs. They sometimes just want data in a specific format (as a JavaScript object) and produce the graph for you.

Comment: @Tintu C Raju i used this link but i am unable to pass array through php

Comment: first made your graph with static data which fits your requirement. Then generate javascript from php. like this
`<?php 
  echo "data.addColumn('number','something');";
?>`

Comment: Do  echo json_encode(your resultset); The use the resulting Json object with Javascript. Mixing php with javascript isn't a good practice

Comment: @YuriBlanc yes your are right its not a good practice. Encode the result to `json` and use `JSON.parse` on client is the best way.